# Formatting Hijri and Gregorian Date

Tags: javascript, date, hijri

I get javascript codes for Hijri+Gregorian date. I want to put Hijri date first and next Gregorian like this:

**Senin, 2 Januari 2017 M / 3 Rabiul Tsani 1438 H**
to
**Senin, 3 Rabiul Tsani 1438 H / 2 Januari 2017 M**

Please help me, because i can't edit javascript codes.
This is the codes:

```js
var fixd;

function isGregLeapYear(year) {
    return year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0;
}

function gregToFixed(year, month, day) {
    var a = Math.floor((year - 1) / 4);
    var b = Math.floor((year - 1) / 100);
    var c = Math.floor((year - 1) / 400);
    var d = Math.floor((367 * month - 362) / 12);

    if (month <= 2)
        e = 0;
    else if (month > 2 && isGregLeapYear(year))
        e = -1;
    else
        e = -2;

    return 1 - 1 + 365 * (year - 1) + a - b + c + d + e + day;
}

function Hijri(year, month, day) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.toFixed = hijriToFixed;
    this.toString = hijriToString;
}

function hijriToFixed() {
    return this.day + Math.ceil(29.5 * (this.month - 1)) + (this.year - 1) * 354 + Math.floor((3 + 11 * this.year) / 30) + 227015 - 1;
}

function hijriToString() {
    var months = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabiul Awwal","Rabiul Tsani","Jumadil Ula","Jumadil Tsani","Rajab","Sya\'ban","Ramadhan","Syawwal","Dzul Qa\'dah","Dzul Hijjah");
    return this.day + " " + months[this.month -1]+ " " + this.year;
}

function fixedToHijri(f) {
    var i=new Hijri(1100, 1, 1);
    i.year = Math.floor((30 * (f - 227015) + 10646) / 10631);
    var i2=new Hijri(i.year, 1, 1);
    var m = Math.ceil((f - 29 - i2.toFixed()) / 29.5) + 1;
    i.month = Math.min(m, 12);
    i2.year = i.year;
    i2.month = i.month;
    i2.day = 1;
    i.day = f - i2.toFixed() + 1;
    return i;
}

var tod=new Date();
var weekday=new Array("Ahad","Senin","Selasa","Rabu","Kamis","Jumat","Sabtu");
var monthname=new Array("Januari","Februari","Maret","April","Mei"," Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember");

var y = tod.getFullYear();
var m = tod.getMonth();
var d = tod.getDate();
var dow = tod.getDay();
document.write(weekday[dow] + ", " + d + " " + monthname[m] + " " + y);
m++;
fixd=gregToFixed(y, m, d);
var h=new Hijri(1421, 11, 28);
h = fixedToHijri(fixd);
document.write(" M / " + h.toString() + " H &nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i can edit it by myself guys, hahaha, even I'm not programmer.
Thank you for your answer. If anyone wan to use this code, here, i'll share it.

```js
function isGregLeapYear(year) 
{ 
return year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0; 
}

function gregToFixed(year, month, day) 
{
var a = Math.floor((year -1) / 4); 
var b = Math.floor((year - 1) / 100); 
var c = Math.floor((year - 1) / 400); 
var d = Math.floor((367 * month - 362) / 12); 

if (month <= 2) 
e = 0; 
else if (month > 2&& isGregLeapYear(year)) 
e = -1; 
else e = -2; 
return 1 - 1 + 365 * (year - 1) + a - b + c + d + e + day; 
} 

function Hijri(year, month, day) 
{ 
this.year = year; 
this.month = month; 
this.day = day; 
this.toFixed = hijriToFixed; 
this.toString = hijriToString; 
} 
function hijriToFixed() 
{ 
return this.day +Math.ceil(29.5 * (this.month - 1)) +(this.year - 1) * 354 + 
Math.floor((3 + 11* this.year) / 30) + 227015 - 1; 
} 
function hijriToString() 
{ 
var months = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabiul Awal","Rabiul Akhir","Jumadil Awal","Jumadil Akhir","Rajab","Sya'ban","Ramadhan","Syawal","Zulqai'dah","Zulhijjah"); 
return this.day + " " +months[this.month -1]+ " " + this.year; 
} 
function fixedToHijri(f) 
{ 
var i=new Hijri(1100, 1, 1); 
i.year = Math.floor((30 * (f - 227015) + 10646) / 10631); 
var i2=new Hijri(i.year, 1, 1); 
var m = Math.ceil((f - 29- i2.toFixed()) / 29.5) + 1; 
i.month = Math.min(m, 12); 
i2.year = i.year; 
i2.month = i.month; 
i2.day = 1; i.day = f - i2.toFixed() + 1; 
return i; 
} 
var tod=new Date(); 
var weekday=new Array ("Ahad","Senin","Selasa","Rabu","Kamis","Jumat","Sabtu"); 
var monthname=new Array("Januari","Februari","Maret","April","Mei"," Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"); 
var y = tod.getFullYear(); 
var m = tod.getMonth(); 
var d = tod.getDate(); 
var dow = tod.getDay(); 
document.write(weekday[dow] + ", "); 
m++; 
fixd=gregToFixed(y, m, d); 
var steve=new Hijri(1421, 11, 28); 
steve = fixedToHijri(fixd); 
document.write(" " + steve.toString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
document.write("/" + " " + d + " " + monthname[m] + " " + y);
m++;
```